# Does the Application.Evaluate method exist in excel js api

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

Does the Application.Evaluate method exist in excel js api? I'd like to run custom functions from the script and get its value. The original method is descsribed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, `evaluate` API is currently not supported so far Excel JS API. I would suggest that you could submit your request on [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563), and upvote your request. Thanks.

A possible workaround You may try: to put the formula that you would like to evaluate into the cell and leverage the Excel calculation engine to get the evaluation result then you could get the value by `range.values` from this cell.